# Copying struct data from host to device on CUDA using cudaMemcpy

Tags: struct, cuda

I am facing a problem in copying struct data from host to device in the CUDA architecture.
Following is the code snippet.

```
struct point  
{  
     double x,y;  
};

int main()  
{  
   point * a = (point*)malloc(sizeof(point));  
   a->x=10.0;   
   a->y=10.0;    
   point * d_a;  
   cudaMalloc((void**)d_a,sizeof(point));  
   cudaMemcpy((void**)d_a,a,sizeof(point),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
   dim3 dimblock(16,16);  
   dim3 dimgrid(1,1);  

   MyFunc<<<dimgrid,dimblock>>>(d_a);  
   cudaMemcpy((void**)a,d_a,sizeof(point),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);    
   printf("%lf %lf\n",a->x,a->y);
}  

__global__ void MyFunc(point* d_a)  
{  
     if(threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
     {  
        d_a->x=100.0;  
        d_a->y = 100.0;    
     }
}
```

The x and y fields of point a should have been changed to 100. Instead, it is still 10 as initialized. What is happening here? Please help.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of both cudaMemcpy() calls is incorrect, they should be

```
cudaMemcpy(d_a,a,sizeof(point),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

and

```
cudaMemcpy(a,d_a,sizeof(point),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

EDIT:

This:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

struct point  
{  
     double x,y;  
};

__global__ void MyFunc(point* d_a)  
{  
     if(threadIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.y == 0)
     {  
        d_a->x=100.0;  
        d_a->y = 100.0;    
     }
}  

int main(void)  
{  
   point * a = (point*)malloc(sizeof(point));  
   a->x=10.0;   
   a->y=10.0;    
   point * d_a;  
   cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,sizeof(point));  
   cudaMemcpy(d_a,a,sizeof(point),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
   dim3 dimblock(16,16);  
   dim3 dimgrid(1,1);  

   MyFunc<<<dimgrid,dimblock>>>(d_a);  
   cudaMemcpy(a,d_a,sizeof(point),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);    
   printf("%lf %lf\n",a->x,a->y);

   return cudaThreadExit();
}
```

works precisely as expected with CUDA 3.2 running on 64 bit linux:

```
cuda:~$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o bungle bungle.cu 
cuda:~$ ./bungle 
100.000000 100.000000
```

So if you cannot replicate this, then something is probably wrong with your CUDA installation.

Comment: I ran this and my terminal is still printing 10 twice !! Is something wrong with my cuda card?

Answer (score 3):

To conclude and extend the answers of Anycorn and talonmies:

1. Use an additional ampersand like `(void**)&d_a` in malloc
2. Don't use `(void**)` in memcpy
3. Make sure to check for errors with `cudaGetLastError` and return values.
4. Make sure to free allocated resources at the end with `cudaFree`
5. Also `cudaSetDevice` and `cudaThreadExit` won't hurt.

See the [reference manual](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_Toolkit_Reference_Manual.pdf) and the [progamming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2_prod/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thanks LumpN but we tried doing all that still no help!! Can there be any other possibility??

Answer (score 1):

check your cuda statuses:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,sizeof(point));
```

Comment: @Vikesh: Note the additional ampersand `&` before `d_a`!